# using list to map tables in HQL

Tags: hql

Im using HQL to create a query in a report application, my query looks like this:

```
from Identity i, Bundle b, IdentityBundles aib
           WHERE b.name LIKE 'DYP%' AND i.bundleSummary LIKE 'DYP%' 
           AND i.id = aib.identityId AND b.id = aib.bundle
```

I have the next error when I tried to run this query:

```
IdentityBundles is not mapped [select count(*) from sailpoint.object.Identity i, sailpoint.object.Bundle b, IdentityBundles aib
```

Looks like there is not mapping to IdentityBundles

The only think that I noticed in the jar files from the application is this list name ( founded in the Identity.hbm.xml file ) with the attributes from the table IdentityBundles

```
 list name="bundles" table="IdentityBundles"
   cascade="persist,merge,save-update">
   key column="identityId"
   list-index column="idx"
   many-to-many column="bundle" class="sailpoint.object.Bundle"
 list
```

Can I use this list to map the table or do I need to create the class and the hbm.xml file ??

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate works with mappings. You are trying to specify the joins and since those are already mapped in your domain objects you don't need to do this. Use the domain object properties instead and Hibernate will fetch them for you.

```
from Identity i 
    join i.bundles b
    where b.name like ...
```

etc.